# Bootstrap v5 fixed badge width

Tags: html, css, sass, bootstrap-5

I have a button with a notifaction badge on it, but whenever the numbers change the size of the badge changes too which is not super nice to look at:

```
    <button class="btn btn-orange w-75 fs-4 mb-3 position-relative">
      Next Round
      <span class="position-absolute top-0 start-100 translate-middle rounded-pill badge bg-secondary fs-6">
        {{ count }}
      </span>
    </button>
```

Note: {{ count }} will become a number between 1 and 9. The problem is when count changes from 1 to 2 for example because 2 has a wider width than 1.

I've tried styling it with a fixed pixel width and height, but the badge never stays in the middle of the badge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `min-width` to the `span`. I found `40px` to fit nicely. Try this:

```html
<button class="btn btn-orange w-75 fs-4 mb-3 position-relative">
    Next Round
    <span class="position-absolute top-0 start-100 translate-middle rounded-pill badge bg-secondary fs-6 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" style="min-width:40px; aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;">
      {{ count }}
    </span>
</button>
```

You can always adjust the `min-width` to a bigger size if you'd like.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hmm max width doesn't stop what I was hoping to stop. The point is {{ count }} will be a number between 1 and 9 and when it changes from 1 to 2, since 2 is wider the whole badge changes size. Ideally I'd like the badge to stay the same size when the number changes. Max-width runs into the same problem I have with width.

Comment: `min-width`, not `max-width`, try again with the code I provided.

Comment: Interesting, ok it does work with a large width. I apologize for not adding this in the question because I didn't realize it would be relevant. But I'd also like the badge to be circular, i.e. width = height (while being relatively small). As well I want the number centered in the badge. I can't seem to do all 3 of these at the same time with this min-width solution so far.

Comment: No problem! I've updated the answer in the code above with the solution. An `aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;` was added to solve this along with some bootstrap flex classes to center the numbers.